# pandas rolling apply to allow nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan, mean

I have a very simple Pandas Series:

```
xx = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5])
```

If I run this I get what I want:

```
>>> xx.rolling(3,1).mean()
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    1.5
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    3.5
6    4.0
```

But if I have to use `.apply()` I cannot get it to work by ignoring `NaN`s in the `mean()` operation:

```
>>> xx.rolling(3,1).apply(np.mean)
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    4.0

>>> xx.rolling(3,1).apply(lambda x : np.mean(x))
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    4.0
```

What should I do in order to both use `.apply()` and have the result in the first output? My actual problem is more complicated that I have to use `.apply()` to realize but it boils down to this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use np.nanmean()

```
xx.rolling(3,1).apply(lambda x : np.nanmean(x))
Out[59]: 
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    1.5
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    3.5
6    4.0
dtype: float64
```

If you have to process the nans explicitly, you can do:

```
xx.rolling(3,1).apply(lambda x : np.mean(x[~np.isnan(x)]))
Out[94]: 
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    1.5
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    3.5
6    4.0
dtype: float64
```